# Swift 3 - Define dictionary with possible two types

Tags: swift, object, dictionary, types, swift3

Is it possible to define dictionray with two types possible for values? Something like:

```
var obj = [String: String, Int]()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend all the types you need with a protocol, and the value have that protocol type:

```
protocol StringOrInt {};
extension String: StringOrInt {}
extension Int: StringOrInt {}

let dict = [String: StringOrInt]()
```

Using an enumeration might be better, though, such as:

```
enum StringOrInt {
  case string(String)
  case int(Int)
}

let obj: [ String : StringOrInt] = [
    "a": .string("Hello"),
    "b": .int(42)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Any` : 
`var someObject : [String:Any] = [:]`